# sql: percentage of a type in a column

Tags: sql, percentage

I'm trying to get percentage of missed calls for each user, so I used the following sql query:

```
select distinct a__contact
       , count (case when a__type = 'missed' 
                     then 1 else 0 end) / count(*) * 100 
                                                  as "percentage of missed calls"

from table
group by 1
```

However, for each user I got 100 which do not seem to be correct output at all. Could someone help me to identify the error in my query? thank you so much!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler way to express the logic you want:

```
select a__contact,
       avg(case when a__type = 'missed' then 100.0 else 0 end) as percentage_missed_calls
from table
group by 1;
```

Your version is failing because you are using `count()` in the numerator.  You really intend `sum()`.  `count()` counts the number of non-`NULL` values and both "1" and "0" are non-`NULL`.

Comment: okay I see your point, using avg does work! thank you so much for your advice :)